# Can I guarantee runnable task continuations have been run?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library, taskcompletionsource

Here's a significantly reduced test case from a piece of code I'm working on:

```c#
var i = 0;

var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
var task = taskCompletionSource.Task;

Task.Run(async () => 
{
    await task;
    i = 1;
});

// Synchronously complete `task`
taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);

// ???

Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Assuming that this code runs in the context of an `async` method, **what should replace `// ???` to ensure that this code prints `1` rather than `0`?**

I believe I understand why as written the program will always print `0` -- the code is executing synchronously and nothing has yielded to the scheduler. But I am surprised to learn that

```
await Task.Yield();
```

doesn't suffice. Somewhat ironically (but perfectly understandably, given that it involves no asynchronous execution) neither does

```
await task;
```

On the other hand,

```
await Task.Delay(1);
```

does seem to be enough, but I'm not clear on whether that's a guarantee or an accident of timing.

To ask the question one more way: is there any (reasonable) code I can write which will guarantee that all continuations for `task` have run before proceeding?

Comment: The written  code does not work because you do not wait for the task that is created from Task.Run(...). You complete `task`, but `Console.WriteLine(i)`is being executed before `i = 1`. But I am unsure of what you are trying to do. See [fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lUAWix)

Comment: The reason `await Task.Delay(1);` works is probably because it forces a thread shift and therefore the task will be executed before `Console.Writeline`.

Comment: As an aside. This is a terrible pattern to use. If the body of the inner method returns some data, you should use `return i;` instead. In that case the initialization will be done in the inner body. This concept is called ENCAPULATION and is one of the four pillars of OOP.

Comment: Closing over `i` is simply an example to illustrate the question, but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I guarantee runnable task continuations have been run?

By `await`ing them.

```
var i = 0;

var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
var task = taskCompletionSource.Task;

var continuation = Task.Run(async () => 
{
    await task;
    i = 1;
});

// Synchronously complete `task`
taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);

// wait for the continuation
await continuation;

// ouputs 1
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

That works if you're withing an asynchronous method. If you're not, make it asynchronous. You can technically block, too, (`.Wait()` instead of `await`) but that invites deadlocks, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming that this code runs in the context of an async method

```
var i = 0;

await Task.Run(async () => 
{
    await task;
    i = 1;
});

Console.WriteLine(i);
```

or

```
var i = 0;

await task;
i = 1;

Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question (`Assuming that this code runs in the context of an async method, what should replace // ??? to ensure that this code prints 1 rather than 0?`)

Comment: Nothing wrong essentially, but it's a rewrite of his code that may not be possible, because he wants to do something between `Task.Run` and `SetResult`.

Comment: Where is that written in the question?

Comment: `significantly reduced test case` and `what should replace // ??? to ensure that this code prints 1 rather than 0?` (the latter in bold).